# Browsing the web using a secondary sound output device

Tags: audio, browser, sound-card, media-player

I use the web for playing music (usually tunein radio). I have two sound cards - one for the computer speakers (primary) and one for my stereo system (secondary). I'm looking for a software - web browser or media player which will allow me to browse the web (for playing music) but use my secondary sound device as the default one.

Today, I use windows media player and BSPlayer for playing media. Both allow me to use the secondary sounds card but they can't browse the web. On the other hand, neither Chrome, Firefox, Opra or Songbird allows me to configure an output device.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using [IndieVolume](http://www.indievolume.com/) which allows me to select a different sound output device for each app.
That way I can use Chrome for browsing and Firefox for music.

> IndieVolume makes Windows programs use separate volume controls
>   independent of other Windows programs.
>
> Bespoke per-application volume, IndieVolume can also make Windows
>   programs shut when GPS speaks, boost too silent sound, propagate
>   sounds to multiple rooms in your apartment and many more.
>
> **Two or more soundcards, but applications play only on one.**
>
> For example, if you have built-in sound card and SoundBlaster as
>   second sound card, or USB/Bluetooth headset, you can configure certain
>   applications play on built-in sound card, and others play on
>   SoundBlaster or USB headset, fully employing your audio hardware.